# Nodes High CPU with Angular2 tutorial

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am working through [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html) Angular 2 tutorial and I have noticed that it is using ~ 160% CPU on my Macbook air, OSX 10.11.2, Node v4.2.4.

I also tried the [Angular 2 seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed) and got the ~ 70% CPU use.

I found some articles on using tick, so I profiled the tutorial and got the following:

```
 [Shared libraries]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
  36178   71.7%    0.0%  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
   7941   15.7%    0.0%  /usr/local/bin/node
    979    1.9%    0.0%  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    978    1.9%    0.0%  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    835    1.7%    0.0%  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    568    1.1%    0.0%  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
     38    0.1%    0.0%  /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
      7    0.0%    0.0%  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
      4    0.0%    0.0%  /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
```

[full log](http://pastebin.com/tJterPt9)

As I am new to both Angular and node, I am at a bit of a loss as to why it is so CPU hungry. The Tick output is not enlightening to me. Any suggestions on how to narrow this down?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, did you able to find solution to your problem...??